# How to return a value from a class to main

Tags: c++, function, class, return

I am trying to build a simple dungeon crawl and am stuck at the battle. The damage taking is working but I cannot return the new health value so that it decreases past the initialized value. Every time the l;oop repeats it returns to the initial value. The same with treasure. What gives? How can I return a value from a member function to main?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class monster
{
public:
    int fight()
    {

    }
};

class chest
{
    int loot()
    {

    }
};

class movement
{
public:
    char wasd()
    {
        char mv;
        char up = 'w';
        char left = 'a';
        char right = 'd';
        char down = 's';

        cout << "\nMove using w for (up), a for (left), d for (right), and s for (down).\n\n";
        mv = _getch();

        if (mv == up)
        {
            cout << "You have moved up 1 space.\n";
        }
        else if (mv == left)
        {
            cout << "You have moved left 1 space.\n";
        }
        else if (mv == right)
        {
            cout << "You have moved right 1 space.\n";
        }
        else if (mv == down)
        {
            cout << "You have moved down 1 space.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "it didn't work.";

        }
        return 0;
    }
};

class random_enc
{   public:
    int treasure;
    int health = 12;
    public:
    int encounter(int)
    {
        int randnumber = rand() % 5 + 1;
        treasure = 0;
        if (randnumber == 1)
        {
            cout << "You have been attacked!!! You lose 1 hitpoint." << endl;
            health = --health;
            cout << "Hitpoints remaining: " << health << endl;
            return health;
        }
        else if (randnumber == 2)
        {
            cout << "You found treasure!" << endl;
            treasure = ++treasure;
            cout << "Treasure collected: " << treasure << endl;;
            return random_enc::treasure;
        }
        else if (randnumber == 3)
        {
            return health;
        }
        else if (randnumber == 4)
        {
            cout << "You step on a trap and take damage!! You lose 1 hit point.\n" << "Good bye." << endl;
            health = --health;
            cout << "Hitpoints remaining: " << health << endl;
        }
        return health;
    }
};



int main()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Welcome to the dungeon, enter your name:\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\nGood luck in the dungeon " << name << "\n";
    int health = 12;

    while (health != 0)
    {
        movement mvmt;
        random_enc random;
        mvmt.wasd();

        random.encounter(health);
    }
    cout << "You have been killed. Goodbye.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Member functions of the class must return a non-`void` type. (2) Implementation of those functions need to return a value of that type AND (3) `main()` needs store the returned value in a variable. In your code, class `movement` has a member named `wasd()` that returns a `char`, and only ever has a `return 0`, so that is the only value that function will ever return.  `main()` creates a `movement` named `mvmt` and then has `mvmt.wasd()` which calls that function and discards the return value. Replace that statement with `char x = mvmt.wasd()` and `x` will have that returned value of zero.

Comment: If I understood correctly it should look like this:
```
 while (health != 0)
 {
  movement mvmt;
  random_enc random;
  mvmt.wasd();
  int health = random.encounter();
 }
```
I did not get the desired results.

Comment: Remove the `int` from `int health = ....` in the loop.   Otherwise you're declaring a variable `health` in the body of the loop, which is distinct from the variable `health` declared outside the loop.   That means the loop condition never changes (since it refers to the variable declared before the loop, and you're storing the result of `random.encounter()` into another variable - which ceases to exist when the loop body completes

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the argument health on the encounter function in random_enc. I replaced it with a pointer: void encounter (int& health)
This passes the reference rather than the value. Then health is defined in the member function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void encounter(int& health)  // note the ampersand
{
    --health; // this will change health in main
}

int main()
{
    int health = 12;
    encounter(health);
    cout << health << '\n';  // prints 11
}
```